# Piglatin : filtering records based on values in bag

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am a newbie to Piglatin, I have a data file that looks like this (message, email, usersession, spamType)

For sake of simplicity I have I have used only spam/not-spam - The value of this field typically is some 100 different variants

```
message1  user1@email  12345      spam
message2  user1@email  12345      spam
message3  user1@email  12345      not-spam

message10  user2@email  90879      not-spam
message11  user2@email  90879      not-spam
```

All I need if any one of the message from one user is marked as spam - Remove/filter all his messages.. So the output of the above would look like

```
message10  user2@email  90879      not-spam
message11  user2@email  90879      not-spam
```

The other 3 messages are removed - Since they are from the same user/session

I am trying to solve the above using grouping and nested for.. Any help appreciated

```
DATA = LOAD './spamdata' using PigStorage() as (message:chararray, mailid:chararray,  session:long, spamType:chararray);
GDATA = GROUP DATA BY (mailid,session);
```

The GDATA looks like

```
GDATA: {group: (message: chararray,session: long),DATA: {(message: chararray,mailid: chararray,session: long,spamType: chararray)}}
```

All I need is to dump the elements from this group where none of the elements in the bag has a 'not-spam' types of element

Answer (score 3):

You can come up with something like this:

```
DATA = LOAD....;
S =  FOREACH (FILTER DATA BY spamType == 'spam') GENERATE mailid, session;
SPAM = DISTINCT S;
JOINED = JOIN DATA BY (mailid, session) LEFT OUTER, SPAM BY (mailid, session);

RES = FOREACH (FILTER JOINED by SPAM::mailid is null)
  GENERATE $0 AS message, $1 AS mailid, $2 AS session, $3 AS spamType;

dump RES;
```

The idea here is to identify first those users who are spammers. After performing a left join with this data on the original data set we can have the list of non-spammers by selecting those rows only where there's no right table match (e.g: SPAM::mailid is null).